# Set Current caretposition in wpf richtextbox viewport Starting?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I already used the below code. It moves current caret position in viewport top.

```
FrameworkContentElement fce = (tpNextLine2.Parent as FrameworkContentElement);
if (fce != null)
{
    fce.BringIntoView();
}
```

the another method is,

```
rtb.ScrollToVerticalOffset(rc.Top + rtb.VerticalOffset);
```

I want to move current caretposition textpointer in richtextbox viewport Starting,i mean hide each word from right to left side using WPF.

How can I achieve this?